# File being read, but not saved

Tags: c, function, struct

I am currently writing a program to read a file and then save the information read to a new file. However when writing the second file no data is saved.

I am using a struct to help break up the text file that I want to use

```
struct file{
    int source;
    int destination;
    int type;
    int port;
    char data[50];
};
```

After reading the file I have created a function to break up the data and print it to the screen

```
int parseFile(int countData, struct file *storedData)
{
    FILE *in_File;

    char buff[1000];


    while(fgets(buff, 1000, in_File)!=NULL)
    {

        printf("%s", buff);

        storedData[countData].source = atoi(strtok(buff, ":"));
        storedData[countData].destination = atoi(strtok(0, ":"));
        storedData[countData].type = atoi(strtok(0, ":"));
        storedData[countData].port = atoi(strtok(0, ":"));
        strcpy(storedData[countData].data, strtok(0, ":\n") );
    }
}
```

and finally I created a function to save the file

```
void saveFile(int countData, struct file *storedData)
{
    FILE *in_File;

    char fileLocation[40];
    int i = 0;

    printf("\nEnter a File Name to save:");
    scanf("%s", fileLocation);

    if ((in_File = fopen(fileLocation, "w")) == NULL){
        puts(" \n Could not point to the file.");
    }else{
        for(i=0;i<countData;i++)
        {
            fprintf(in_File, "%04d:%04d:%04d:%04d:%s \n",
                    storedData[i].source,
                    storedData[i].destination,
                    storedData[i].type,
                    storedData[i].port,
                    storedData[i].data );
        }
    }
        fclose(in_File);
}
```

In the main function I used malloc to allocate the size of the struct

```
int main()
{
    struct file *storedData;
    storedData = malloc(sizeof(struct file));

    int countData = 0;

    banner();
    readFile(countData, storedData);
    parseFile(countData, storedData);
    saveFile(countData, storedData);

    return 0;
}
```

When getting the data and running it through my parseFile function each line is written out to me line by line

Example of data output:

```
0001:0002:0003:0021:CLS 
0003:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000030
0006:0003:0002:0041:100000000000000000019
0006:0002:0002:0060:100000000000000000020
```

However when saved to a file none of this output is stored and I was wondering what I could do to fix it

EDIT:

Here is the readFile function:

```
void readFile(int countData, struct file *storedData)
{
    FILE *in_File;

    char fileLocation[40];

    printf("\nEnter file name: \n");
    scanf("%s", fileLocation);

    in_File = fopen(fileLocation, "r");

    if(!in_File)
    {
        printf("\nError!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the name `in_File` for an output file stream is a little counter-intuitive, is it not?

Comment: Are you using `write` or `fwrite`?

Comment: I can't see in parseFile how you open in_File before reading it.

Comment: Can you show readFile ?

Comment: Obvious things to print in `saveFile()` are the value of `countData` on entry to the function, and do a `printf()` as well as the `fprintf()` of the data.  Since you never pass `countData` as a pointer to any function, it remains zero in `main()`, so your printing code never prints anything.  Your `readFile()` function either needs to return the value to be assigned to `countData` or needs to be passed `&countData` and then modified to assign to this pointer.

Comment: You never close `in_file` in `parsefile()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
storedData = malloc(sizeof(struct file));
```

Allocates enough for ONE file record.

Your routine `parseFile()` would write over that record repeatedly, but as it never increments `countData` it doesn't write any -- although even if it did, the parent routines would not receive your updated countData, as you would have had to pass an `int *` of `&countData` to let the `parseFile()` routine increment it.

Since `for(i=0;i<countData;i++)` is present, you never even read a single line, since `0 < 0` is false.

If you make that change, as soon as you hit the second record, you will overwrite memory and coredump because you only allocated one record worth of space in `main()`

Also in `parseFile()`, you have to open the file before reading it! Something like:

```
in_File = fopen(inputFileName, "r");
```

[edit] I see you updated with `readFile()` -- it needs to return the open FILE * for use by parseFile, and you will need to pass that FILE * to parseFile to use.

Comment: In addition, you may want to take a look at how `in_File` is used in `parseData`, and more importantly, *where it comes from*. As soon as your fix here (which is correct) is applied, that bag-o-worms will rear its ugly head.